# Hibernate criterion to restrict property to set of possibilities including null

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm still trying to understand how the `Restrictions.in("propName", ...)` operator of the Hibernate `Criteria` object works.

Let's say I have an entity `IceCream` with nullable property `flavour` and I want to get all ice creams where flavour equals `"chocolate"`, `"banana"` or `null`.

What is the correct way to do this using Hibernate criteria?

I tried this but it doesn't include rows where the icecream flavour is null in the result list:

```
String[] allowedFlavours = { "chocolate", "banana", null };
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(IceCream.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("flavour", allowedFlavours));
return criteria.list();
```

Should I instead add a whole new criterion just to say "or flavour is null"? This just doesn't seem very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

1>

```
 Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(IceCream.class);
    criteria .add(Restrictions.disjunction().add(Restrictions.eq("flavour", "chocolate")).add(Restrictions.eq("flavour", "banana")).add(Restrictions.isNull("flavour")));
```

2>

```
String[] allowedFlavours = { "chocolate", "banana"};
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(IceCream.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.disjunction().add(Restrictions.in("flavour", allowedFlavours)).add(Restrictions.isNull("flavour"));


return criteria.list();
```

Comment: If I'm given a list of allowed flavours at runtime I don't know if null is contained in the allowedFlavours list. I would have rathered a solution that didn't require me to interrogate that list in order to build up the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code using `disjunction()`

> **disjunction** : Group expressions together in a single disjunction (A or B or C...)

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(IceCream.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.disjunction()
    .add( Restrictions.isNull("flavour") )
    .add(Restrictions.in("flavour", new String[] { "chocolate", "banana" } ) );
```

*Please add/remove brackets, format code appropriately as I have typed it manually.*

Comment: this is exactly the same as Pradeep's answer #2 above.

Comment: @Lisa Probably another post was edited afterwards or it's mine oversight.